# configure time tag subscription mails are sent

Tags: feature-request, email

Tag subscription mails always reach me as I’m about to go to bed, which is kinda annoying, as I either oversleep on the next day or can’t answer immediately.

Is there a method to configure the time those are sent out?

Comment: You could always, you know, not answer immediately... Or mute the notification of new emails around bed time... :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan arrrrrrrrgh the temptation!!!!! ☺